# Display user HTML on website

Tags: theme-options, options

I have a settings page in Wordpress that lets the Admin enter HTML Code. I want to display this code at a specific page on the website using a shortcode.

My problem now is that the shortcode displays the HTML instead of executing it:

[image]

Here is my function:

```
function MKWD_Display_Westmor_Bottom_Left() {
  $westmor_customers_options = get_option( 'westmor_customers_option_name' );
  return $westmor_customers_options['homepage_bottom_left_widget_0'];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably need to unescape the html on output. If you inspect the code on the front-end is it a bunch of symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to un-escape the output. Take a look at [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) or similar functions before outputting to the screen.

```
$orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";

$a = htmlentities($orig);

$b = html_entity_decode($a);

echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now

echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
```

---

[html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

```
function MKWD_Display_Westmor_Bottom_Left() {
  $westmor_customers_options = get_option( 'westmor_customers_option_name' );
  return html_entity_decode ( $westmor_customers_options['homepage_bottom_left_widget_0'] );
}
```

---

[htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

```
function MKWD_Display_Westmor_Bottom_Left() {
  $westmor_customers_options = get_option( 'westmor_customers_option_name' );
  return htmlspecialchars_decode ( $westmor_customers_options['homepage_bottom_left_widget_0'] );
}
```

---

[wp_specialchars_decode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_specialchars_decode/)

```
function MKWD_Display_Westmor_Bottom_Left() {
  $westmor_customers_options = get_option( 'westmor_customers_option_name' );
  return wp_specialchars_decode ( $westmor_customers_options['homepage_bottom_left_widget_0'] );
}
```

---

[stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

```
function MKWD_Display_Westmor_Bottom_Left() {
  $westmor_customers_options = get_option( 'westmor_customers_option_name' );
  return stripslashes ( $westmor_customers_options['homepage_bottom_left_widget_0'] );
}
```

Comment: html_entity_decode worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!