# Render the metabox input values as HTML

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, escaping

I'm new to PHP and WordPress.

I've created a site on WordPress, where the user can add an HTML code snippet (the inputs are taken using a metabox and displayed). The problem is WordPress doesn't render the input's value, rather it converts it to ASCII and displays the HTML code snippet as raw HTML rather than rendering it.

Is there any solution for this? In certain parts of the template I would like to display the rendered HTML, and also the escaped (raw) HTML.

Please note that I am using a custom metabox in a custom post type. I generated the metabox using [this generator](http://jeremyhixon.com/tool/wordpress-meta-box-generator/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to output trusted html, use [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

```
$orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";

$a = htmlentities($orig);

$b = html_entity_decode($a);

echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now

echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
```

You can find more examples [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/213398/84219).